# How do I reanalyze GCP IAM roles to identify excess permissions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

GCP IAM has a really handy feature that helps you identify excess permissions for the roles granted to an IAM user. I assume this works by analyzing API calls and activity by a user to see what permissions are actually being exercised and comparing that to the permissions included in the roles granted to that user.

In the GCP console, under IAM, in the list of users and service accounts, you can click on the numbers on the right next to each role to see which permissions are used. In that list of permissions, it says "Last Analyzed (Date)". For me, this is a few days ago and I'd like updated results based on activity since then.

Is there a way to request IAM reanalyze the permissions? Or is it a scheduled job that I have to wait for?

Thanks!

Comment: This page seems to say that the analysis happens on an "ongoing" basis ...

https://cloud.google.com/recommender/docs/overview#process

There doesn't appear to be a declaration of how often nor that it is manually triggerable.

Comment: Customization is in the roadmap. For now, you have to wait at least 90 days, and the process is triggered periodically (you don't know when and you can't force it). I'm going to talk to the PM next week. If you have special feedback/requirement, I can't share them with her!

Comment: The IAM recommender evaluates only role grants that were made at the project level, and that have existed for at least 90 days.. Analyzed permissions list the excess permissions not needed for this member. This was determined by analyzing 90 days of permissions utilization data using machine learning [1](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/recommender-overview).

Comment: The IAM Recommender  Observation period is the time period leading up to the insight. The source data used to generate the insight ends atlast_refresh_time and begins at last_refresh_time minus observation_period [2](https://cloud.google.com/recommender/docs/insights/using-insights#observation_period)